# R kruskal_test disagrees with GraphPad Prism Calculation for Kruskal_test

Tags: r, stat

I am new to stackoverflow, but I have a question regarding kruskal_test function in R.

my dataframe:

```
Y<-c(666,500,400,500,300,100,100,267,490,525,50,30,55,100,70)
Group<- 
   c("a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c")
validation_1<-data.frame(Y,Group)
validation_1 %>% kruskal_test(Y~Group)
#this is the result

# A tibble: 1 x 6
  .y.       n statistic    df      p method        
* <chr> <int>     <dbl> <int>  <dbl> <chr>         
1 Y        15      9.71     2 0.0078 Kruskal-Wallis
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8UKL.png)

However, GraphPad Prism is giving me a different result.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfE1p.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKvo3.png)

Does anyone know why? Thank you very much

Comment: The values for the Kruskal Test are the same. The p-value estimates differ slightly. With small sample sizes there can be differences in how the p-value is computed: exact, asymptotic, and Monte Carlo.

Comment: Hi. Thank you.  Is there a way to specify that in the R script?

Comment: The `kruskal.test()` uses Chi Square, `pchisq(9.71, 2, lower.tail=FALSE) == 0.007789333`. I do not know how GraphPad Prism computes "exact" p-values. See [Kruskal-Wallis test data considerations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8846/kruskal-wallis-test-data-considerations), [Wilcoxon Rank-Sum: computing the exact -value](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/176297/wilcoxon-rank-sum-computing-the-exact-p-value), and [Kruskal-Wallis test: how to calculate the exact p-value?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319873/kruskal-wallis-test-how-to-calculate-the-exact-p-value).